# date and time (local time instead of UTC) (Maxima)

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, maxima

These lines give the date and time in UTC:

```
t:timedate(absolute_real_time() - (10*3600));
t0:substring(t,1,20);
t1:concat(substring(t,12,17), " ", substring(t,9,11), "/", substring(t,6,8), "/", substring(t,1,5));
t2:concat(substring(t,1,5), substring(t,6,8), substring(t,9,11), substring(t,12,14), substring(t,15,17), substring(t,18,20));
```

I know that '?\*autoconf\-version\*;' can give the Maxima version number, so maybe there is some undocumented way to get the local time.

Otherwise are there any ready-made functions that can convert
UTC time to local time given conditions for start/end of daylight saving time
e.g. UTC time to UK time (which is GMT/BST depending on the time of year)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the problem, before revealing the solution:
these are the steps that I take in Maxima v5.30
to get the time in UTC, in a readable format:

Note: When I use Maxima v5.30 (in the UK),
for some unknown reason, the time is always UTC adjusted
by 10 hours, and does not adjust for DST.

```
/* 1st Jan 2017 12 noon: */
timedate(3692260800); /* "2017-01-01 22:00:00+10:00" */
timedate(3692260800-10*3600); /* "2017-01-01 12:00:00+10:00" */
substring(timedate(3692260800-10*3600),1,20); /* "2017-01-01 12:00:00" */
```

Note: timedate works better/differently in later versions of Maxima,
but some institutions recommend installing a specific version of Maxima.

Sometimes I want the date in the form: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'.
A function for this is:

```
SecUTCToDate(vSec,vHour):=
block([d1,d2],
d1:timedate(vSec+vHour*3600),
d2:concat(substring(d1,1,5), substring(d1,6,8), substring(d1,9,11), substring(d1,12,14), substring(d1,15,17), substring(d1,18,20)),
parse_string(d2)
);
```

Note: `[d1,d2]` keeps those variables local to within the block, and not global.

To get the local time I have to add on hours based on my time zone (0 in the UK), and DST.
To calculate whether a time is within the DST period requires an individual function per time zone: in the UK, and many European countries, one such function is:

```
/* correct for the years 1900-2200 inclusive */
SecUTCIsDSTUK(vSec):=
block([vLeap,vDaysMar25,vDaysOct25,vWDayMar25,vWDayOct25,vRange1,vRange2],
vYear : parse_string(substring(timedate(vSec),1,5)),
vLeap : floor((vYear-1900)/4), if (vYear>=2100) then vLeap : vLeap-1,
vDaysMar25 : (vYear-1900)*365 + vLeap + 83,
vDaysOct25 : vDaysMar25 + 214,
vWDayMar25 : mod(vDaysMar25+1,7),
vWDayOct25 : mod(vDaysOct25+1,7),
vRange1 : (vDaysMar25+mod(-vWDayMar25,7))*86400 + 3600,
vRange2 : (vDaysOct25+mod(-vWDayOct25,7))*86400 + 3600,
if ((vSec >= vRange1) and (vSec < vRange2)) then 1 else 0);
```

You can create a mac file with such a function, and call up the the function when needed, e.g.:

```
load("C:\\MyFolder\\MyFile.mac");
SecUTCIsDSTUK(absolute_real_time());
SecUTCIsDSTUK(absolute_real_time()+86400*180);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me exactly what you need, but perhaps the following helps. By the way, do you really need to extract the parts (year, month, day, etc)? If so, it might be more convenient to work directly in Lisp. See DECODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME at the Common Lisp Hyperspec (a web search will find it).

The `timedate` now (in the just-released Maxima 5.39) accepts an optional argument which is the time zone offset, in hours (plus or minus). The time zone offset may be noninteger (e.g. 2.5). Offset 0 indicates UTC. If the offset is omitted, the time is formatted in the local time zone.

```
(%i5) t:absolute_real_time();
(%o5)                             3691202499
(%i6) timedate (t, 0);
(%o6)                      2016-12-20 06:01:39+00:00
(%i7) timedate (t);
(%o7)                      2016-12-19 22:01:39-08:00
```

Note that the daylight saving time flag is applied at the "time of the time". Here is a time from next summer, when daylight saving time is in effect.

```
(%i8) timedate (t + 6*30.25*24*3600);
(%o8)                      2017-06-19 11:01:39-07:00
```

The `parse_timedate` function has also been (in Maxima 5.39) updated to recognize time zone offsets.

```
(%i9) parse_timedate ("2016-12-19 22:01:39-08:00");
(%o9)                             3691202499
```

As with `timedate` if the offset is omitted, it is assumed to be in the local time zone.

```
(%i10) parse_timedate ("2016-12-19 22:01:39");
(%o10)                            3691202499
```

Note also that Maxima does not recognize any symbolic time zone indicators such as "UTC", "GMT", "EDT", "America/New_York", etc., only numerical time zone offsets.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your helpful response,

results (v. 5.39.0) (works fine, param 2 omitted gives local time, param 2 as 0 gives UTC):

```
t:3691202499;
timedate (t);
timedate (t + 6*30.25*24*3600);
timedate (t + 6*30*24*3600);
timedate (t, 0);
timedate (t + 6*30.25*24*3600, 0);
timedate (t + 6*30*24*3600, 0);
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3691202499)
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3691202499 0)
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3706754499)
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3706754499 0)

3691202499
"2016-12-20 06:01:39+00:00"
"2017-06-19 19:01:39+01:00"
"2017-06-18 07:01:39+01:00"
"2016-12-20 06:01:39+00:00"
"2017-06-19 18:01:39+00:00"
"2017-06-18 06:01:39+00:00"
39 1 6 20 12 2016 1 NIL 0
39 1 6 20 12 2016 1 NIL 0
39 1 7 18 6 2017 6 T 0
39 1 6 18 6 2017 6 NIL 0
```

results (v. 5.30.0) (it seems param 2 omitted gives UTC+10, with no daylight saving time):
(if this is true, I would have to find another way to get local time, possibly by Common LISP commands)

```
t:3691202499;
timedate (t);
timedate (t + 6*30.25*24*3600);
timedate (t + 6*30*24*3600);
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3691202499)
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3691202499 0)
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3706754499)
:lisp (decode-universal-time 3706754499 0)

3691202499
"2016-12-20 16:01:39+10:00"
"2017-06-20 04:01:39.0+10:00"
"2017-06-18 16:01:39+10:00"
39 1 16 20 12 2016 1 NIL -10
39 1 6 20 12 2016 1 NIL 0
39 1 16 18 6 2017 6 NIL -10
39 1 6 18 6 2017 6 NIL 0
```

(I can see that the timedate and decode-universal-time functions
have key differences between Maxima versions)

thank you for the website mention,
CLHS: Section The Environment Dictionary
http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/c_enviro.htm

is there a list of LISP commands that work in Maxima?

the main reason for the datestamp concerns:
to produce datestamps for filenames such as 'z title yyyymmddhhmmss.txt',
or for friendly dates inside those files such as 'hh:mm dd/mm/yyyy',
the string manipulation method was the simplest method
that I could successfully code (I don't explicitly need to extract individual d m y etc)

Comment: Well, DECODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME is a Lisp function and it doesn't change from one Maxima version to another. But it's possible that the Lisp implementations of your 5.30 version and the 5.39 version are different. Anyway, 5.30 is pretty old at this point; it doesn't worth the trouble to figure out what's going on. If you have 5.39, just use that. About creating timestamps for filenames, maybe something like this: `s:timedate(...); ssubst("_", " ", (ssubst ("_", ":", s)));` i.e. use the string substitution function `ssubst` to fix up a `timedate` output.

Comment: As to which Lisp functions work in Maxima, all Lisp functions work in Maxima if they are called via `:lisp (foo ...)` and most of them work if they are called via `?foo(...)` where FOO is a Lisp function. `?? Lisp` finds some relevant info in the on-line reference manual.

Comment: A simpler way to do the substitution, I've found, is to use `regex_substitute` (sorry, it's undocumented). Example: `regex_subst("_", "[ :-]", timedate())` yields `"2016_12_25_14_28_31_08_00"`. There are other regex functions; see `share/stringproc/sregex.lisp`.

Comment: Is it possible to use 'DECODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME' in a line that starts with a '?', and export the items to a list. (I spent a good deal of time trying and researching but failed to do it.) -- More generally is there are a good page with some Maxima/LISP examples (I looked for these too). -- Also, are there any LISP functions the average user might be interested in using, because I had a look through the CLHS list and didn't find many.

Comment: Well, you can call DECODE-UNIVERSAL-TIME as `?decode\-universal\-time()` in Maxima, but it returns multiple values (this is a Common Lisp concept) and Maxima doesn't know what to do with them. You'll have to wrap the call in something that Maxima understands, e.g.: `:lisp (defun $foo (time tz) (cons '(mlist) (multiple-value-list (decode-universal-time time tz))))` and then e.g. `foo(0, 0)` yields `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1900, 0, false, 0]` in Maxima. I don't a good reference for Maxima/Lisp examples; if you have specific questions, the maxima-discuss mailing list is a good place to ask.

Comment: About useful Lisp functions, you can take a look at tutorials such as "The Common Lisp Cookbook" or "Practical Common Lisp". Common Lisp is an interesting and useful language, and worth learning in its own right.

Comment: Well I don't like to give up too quickly on things,
I was hoping to make 2 GMT/BST from/to date functions,
compatible with 5.30 and 5.39, partly to test my Maxima/LISP skills.
-- They would need to retrieve the weekday index, and convert
YMDHMS to S, however if 'block (?sleep(1));' works but 'block (:lisp (sleep 1));'
doesn't, i.e. if you can't use ':lisp' in a function or block, I'm not sure if I can proceed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am writing a guide to Maxima,
the link will appear on my profile page within the next few months.
-- My queries are done for the medium term, although I can envisage
some possible append to txt issues in the future.
-- At present, resolving Maxima problems usually takes 2 to 3 times more searching time than other queries.
It's only going to take a few good manuals online for the popularity
of Maxima to skyrocket. This series of videos was invaluable to me.
Maxima CAS Tutorials - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEDEE2F7C6750729F

Comment: When you have further questions, my advice is to ask on the Maxima mailing list. See: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/maximalist.html

Comment: It's true that you can't put `:lisp` inside `block`, but the point of defining a function such as `:lisp (defun $foo ...)` as I was showing before is that `foo` is then a function that you can call from Maxima and it returns a result that Maxima understands.